# How may a web page that is loaded via https connect to a WebSocket server running on localhost?

Tags: javascript, firefox, https, websocket, localhost

I'm trying to create a web page that can connect to a client-local WebSocket server. The idea is to use the JavaScript client running in the browser as kind of a proxy to enable communication between the remote web server and the locally installed client application which implements the WebSocket service.

So basially, what I'd do is load a web page from https://example.com which includes some JavaScript that opens a new WebSocket to ws://localhost:1234/context.
This works fine as long as the web page is accessed via http. **As soon as https is used**, however, Firefox and Internet Explorer **refuse to connect** and the WebSocket constructor throws an exception (SecurityError, code 18).
Now, I already found advice from Mozilla stating that https sites should only use secure (wss://) WebSockets and plain http sites should only use plain WebSockets ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Security_considerations)). But I don't really see the security issue when connecting to localhost from within an https context. Besides, this works like a charm for Chrome, Opera and Safari.

So the actual question is: Is there any way to work around this issue? Like introducing a non-https context inside the web page or something similar to get all browsers to connect to ws://localhost from within a https-delivered web page?

Thanks a lot in advance! I'm not exactly a web developer so this kind of browser-specific behaviour isn't really in my fields of expertise :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to accept the cert first.

You can do this by simply going to `https://localhost:1234/context`, in your case.  Once that's done, you can use the `wss` URL in your question.